# Access angularjs i18n date/time and currency formatting in application

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I have an angular project with multiple locale config files--e.g. en-us.json, es-es.json, etc.

I have a need within my application to extract the date/time and number format data for the currently active locale.  The extracted formats are to be massaged and passed into an external service that generates a report.

The basic flow would be:

1. User views a result page
2. User clicks button to generate report
3. Client app uses active locale to look up date/time and number formats defined in xx-xx.json files
4. format data sent to server, which massages the data and sends it to an external report generation service

So, what is the best way to access the formats set in the angular xx-xx.json files?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the piece I was missing was the use of $locale

e.g.,

this.$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.formatDay